# Duplicate key value being tracked for lookup table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 7 and SQL Server in a Blazor Server app. I know there are thousands of threads on this error but I've tried everything to fix this:

> The instance of entity type 'ChangeStatusType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ChangeStatusTypeId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

My entity relationships are:

- `ChangeRequest` has many `Changes`
- Each `Change` can have many `ChangeStatus`
- Each `ChangeStatus` can have one `ChangeStatusType`.

If I create one new change with one change status and one change status type, everything works fine.

If I create multiple changes, each with one change status and one change status type, that's when I run into the error.

Here is the relevant part of my `CREATE` method where I'm preparing to save the ChangeStatus'. In the inner `FOREACH` it runs through the first change just fine, then on the second it throws the error when it try to set the `changeStatus` to `EntityState.Added`. In this instance, each `ChangeStatus` only has one `ChangeStatusType` but since it's a list, I still have to loop through it.

```
foreach (var change in addedChanges)
{
    context.Entry(change).State = EntityState.Added;

    foreach (var changeStatus in change.ChangeStatuses)
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(changeStatus, x => { x.Entry.State = EntityState.Added; });
        context.Attach(changeStatus.StatusTypes);
    }
}

context.AddRange(addedChanges);

var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've also tried using the `ChangeTrack.TrackGraph` to set the status of the `ChangeStatus`. Here are the change, status and status type entities. The `ChangeStatus.StatusTypeId` field has the correct values and the `ChangeStatus.StatusType` entity is populated also. I double-checked that the `TypeId` exists in the `ChangeStatusType` table.

```
public class ChangeStatus
{
    #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by EF.
    /// </summary>
    public ChangeStatus() { }
    #pragma warning restore CS8618 

    public int? ChangeStatusId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChangeDetail.ChangeDetailId))]
    public int? ChangeDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")] 
    public string SubmitUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Required]
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChangeStatusType.ChangeStatusTypeId))]
    public int ChangeStatusTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ChangeStatusType StatusTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChangeDetail> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeStatusType
{
    #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by EF.
    /// </summary>
    public ChangeStatusType() { }
    #pragma warning restore CS8618 

    public int ChangeStatusTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StatusTypeName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

UPDATE: As requested, here is the code block with Steve's changes

```
foreach (var change in addedChanges)
{
    context.ChangeDetail.Add(change);
 // Change.ChangeStatuses will already be treated as "Added" but we don't want references to be treated as Add.
    foreach (var changeStatus in change.ChangeStatuses)
    {                                   //context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(changeStatus, x => { x.Entry.State = EntityState.Added; });
     var existingStatusType = context.ChangeStatusType.Local
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ChangeStatusTypeId == changeStatus.StatusTypes.ChangeStatusTypeId);
     if (existingStatusType != null)
       changeStatus.StatusTypes = existingStatusType;
    else
       context.Attach(changeStatus.StatusTypes);
    }

  foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
  {
    var entityName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
    var state = entry.State.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(state + " " + entityName);
  }
}
```

I added the ForEach at the end to check the status of the entities and its showing StatusTypes as Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with detached entities, especially graphs of entities, you need to be explicitly careful when it comes to handling any references to existing data. Within a change you have ChangeStatus entries which will be added, but each change status references a ChangeStatusType, which is a limited set of existing values. When saving a single status you would either attach it's status type, or end up trying to insert a new status type. When inserting two statuses, it might work as long as the statuses had a different status type, but otherwise you get the tracking reference issue.

```
foreach (var change in addedChanges)
{
    // Change.ChangeStatuses will already be treated as "Added" but we don't want references to be treated as Add.
    foreach (var changeStatus in change.ChangeStatuses)
    {
        //context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(changeStatus, x => { x.Entry.State = EntityState.Added; });
        var existingStatusType = context.StatusType.Local
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StatusTypeId == changeStatus.StatusTypes.StatusTypeId);
        if (existingStatusType != null)
            changeStatus.StatusTypes = existingStatusType
        else
            context.Attach(changeStatus.StatusTypes);
    }
    // Edit: yes, the reference updates need to be done before adding the parent..
    context.Changes.Add(change);
}
```

Essentially the difference here is that we don't want to treat the entire graph as Added. When adding the Change, the ChangeStatuses will automatically be treated as Added, which we want, but we don't want the Status.StatusTypes treated as added. Instead, we check each one against the `.Local` tracking cache, and if found, replace the reference with the tracked status. If it isn't tracked, then we track it by attaching. When we get to the next change status, it will resolve that tracked reference when checked if the status types match.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the assist but its not solving my error.  I added a `print` statement to for change status in ChangeTracking and Type is `Added`: 
`Added ChangeStatus`
`Added ChangeDetail`
`Added ChangeStatusType`

Looking at your code, It appears you are assigning the StatusType object (in the new status) to the corresponding local tracking cache object.  But the new status object is not in local context as its a Create action?  If I change it to be an Attach (like the else), ChangeStatus doesn't show up in ChangeTracking?

Comment: I was wrong, if I move `context.Attach(changeStatus.StatusTypes)`  from the ELSe to the IF, then StatusType is listed in the tracking as `Unchanged` but throws the same error.

Comment: The code queries the ChangeStatusTypes local tracking cache in the DbContext. If it finds one, you need to replace the reference in your new ChangeStatus to point at the existing tracked instance, Otherwise you can attach the reference. It should be marked as "Unchanged" when attached as we are inserting a ChangeStatus,with a new association to a status type, the ChangeStatusType itself is not being updated.

Comment: yea, i get that now but getting the same error.

Comment: If you are replacing the ChangeStatusType with the tracked reference you would not be getting the exact same error, possibly the same error but with a different navigation property, but not on the change status type. Please update your question with the updated code that you are running based on the suggestion I made to replace the reference with the tracked one.

Comment: finally figured it out.  `context.ChangeDetail.Add(change);` needed to be after looping through the StatusType.

Comment: Ah yes, adding the ChangeDetail would add the detached references so the existing reference substitution does need to occur first. I corrected the example in the answer.